# How to preserve git history when refactoring into multiple files

Tags: git

I have a SCSS file that is ugly. I want to split it up into multiple other files to make it easier to work with.

If my file is,

```
file.scss
```

I want to finish with something like,

```
file.scss
file-sm.scss
file-md.scss
file-lg.scss
```

`sm`, `md`, and `lg` will all have significant portions of the original `files.scss` so I want to preserve/copy history on them to make it easier on future development and future developers.

How can I refactor a file into multiple new files and preserve, or copy over, history to the new files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git has built-in rename / copy detection based on file similarity. To ensure it kicks in, first do a plain copy of `file.scss` to all of `file-{sm,md,lg}.scss` and commit these files. Then delete the unwanted portions from these files, remove `file.scss`, and commit again. Now e.g. a `git log --follow --find-copies file-sm.scss` should show `file-sm.scss`'s history including the one of `file.scss`.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to make one commit involving both the old and new file(s) for git to associate them in the future.

Make a copy of the original but don't change the new files just yet:

```
cp file.scss file-sm.scss
cp file.scss file-md.scss
cp file.scss file-lg.scss
```

Make a minor temporary change to the original to have it committed along with the new ones:

```
echo "// refactoring: split the file" >> file.scss
```

Commit the changes:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Refactor: splitting up file.scss"
```

Now you can see the history of the old file when you use `--follow` and `-C1` flags:

```
git log --follow file-lg.scss
git blame -C1 file-lg.scss
```

Clean up the "// refactoring .." comment and proceed with refactoring.

**+1** for preserving history while refactoring - future developers will thank you.

Comment: What benefit does touching the original file have when bringing in the copies of the original file?  (The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38729894/115751) omits this step.)