# How do I refactor my code to a new file and preserve git history?

Tags: git, refactoring

So I want to extract a part of a large file to a new one and to preserve git history, so I'll be able to run `git blame` and see the changes as before the refactoring.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking... Can you give an example perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preserve git history when refactoring into multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729453/how-to-preserve-git-history-when-refactoring-into-multiple-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Git, the history *is* the commits.  There is no file history.  This is unlike most other version control systems: Those other VCSes that *do* track "file identity" need you to inform them that new file `path/to/new.ext` is derived from `path/to/existing.ext` so that they can associate the new file's history with the old file's history.  Similarly, they need you to inform them about file renames—although some, like ClearCase, can auto-detect renames by simply *acting as* the file system for the work-tree.  Git does not need any of this because it does not work that way.<sup>1</sup>

Instead, in Git, when you compare one commit—call it `a`—to another (`b`), Git attempts to *discover* (dynamically, at compare-time) whether some file `a/path/to/name` is "the same" as another file `b/some/other/path/to/anothername`.  The degree of comparison and the algorithm for deciding that these *are* the same file, or are different files, are up to the Git command.  The `git diff` command starts by looking at the actual path names: if they are the same, the files are the same,<sup>2</sup> otherwise they are *probably* different.  The "probably" part is where rename detection comes in, if you have enabled it.  A regular `git diff` also has `-C` and `--find-copies-harder` to enable "file-copied-from" detection.  Using `-C` twice (or `--find-copies-harder`) sets things up to look for new files being copied from *any* file in the `a` commit (this is considered too expensive to do automatically; normally, only files that are otherwise considered "modified" are treated as source-of-copy candidates).

The `git blame` command is somewhat different (and the `a` and `b` commits are just automatically parent-and-child of each commit), but it still has a `-C` option.  Its `-C` works a bit differently: one `-C` looks for *lines* copied from files modified between commits `a` and `b`.  Using `-C` twice looks for such lines copied from *any* file in commit `a`, and with three `-C` flags, it will "find copies harder still": it will look at every file in *every* commit to find copied code.

Hence, for most purposes you can just use one `-C` on your `git blame`.  You should use `-C -C` if the copied code comes from a non-modified file.  Use three `-C`s if you believe some code was deleted many revs ago, then resurrected, and you want to find the original source.  Note that `git blame`'s `-C` option turns on `git blame`'s `-M` option, which detects *moved* code (and is therefore quite different from `git diff`'s `-M` option—file rename detection, a la `git log --follow`,<sup>3</sup> is always enabled).

---

<sup>1</sup>This is a nice advantage for Git over other VCSes, because Git can detect cases that humans forgot, and also can detect renames when comparing "far apart" revisions.  It's a terrible disadvantage for Git, because it must *detect* cases even if humans would not have forgotten, and hence misses renames.  It's a big advantage for Git, because future smarter algorithms use the existing data in better ways.  In short, there are arguments for why it's better and why it's worse, but ultimately it's just *different*.

<sup>2</sup>For `git diff`, you can conditionally break apart these automatically-paired "same name means same file" pairings using its `-B` option.  This is unavailable to, yet unnecessary for, `git blame`, which is not doing this kind of pairing.

<sup>3</sup>The code enabled by `--follow` in `git log` is a horrible hack that basically only works for the one case required by `git blame`.  Do not try to use `--follow` with reverse-order `git log`.

Comment: It's not that 'Git does not need' that, Git does not _want_ to do that, or rather Torvalds chose not to have it do it when he designed Git, believing that it wasn't necessary. Heuristics is a thing that _any_ VCS could do it if it wanted, it's just that those that explicitly store the user intent have no need to do it, because they already know what **really** happened. Heuristics work in simple cases but are doomed to fail miserably in some, however smart the algorithm is (yes, I know that almost no VCS stores anything more than file renames, sadly)

Comment: @gbr: True. Git currently does not have a place for such metadata, although since it's just a file system masquerading as a VCS :-) one could add it retroactively. The main problem would be Git's index: you would need either a side file, or a new index format.

Comment: sure, there are various ways it could be added, I don't see the maintainers well-disposed towards this kind of big changes, though

Comment: @torek thank you and upvote for this extensive explanation, really helpful. Git blame is very useful, sure we all use it. But back to my question, how can you practically copy a part of file A into a new file B keeping the `git blame` information inside B?

Comment: @valk: basically, just move the code and hope that `git blame` finds the code motion. If it doesn't, try a lower value for `-M` and/or `-C`. If none of those works, you can try coding up new algorithms for `git blame`...

Comment: @valk Your best best is to ensure your changes are "atomic". If you're copying a file and changing it, copy it in one commit and change it in another. Since git uses the percentage change for its heuristics, this will help ensure it can detect the change.